# Joomla ACL for specific view in custom component

Tags: php, joomla2.5, acl

I've written an extension and I'm now trying integrate it into the ACL. I've been using the documentation here: http://docs.joomla.org/Developing_a_Model-View-Controller_Component/2.5/Adding_ACL

Thus far I've been able to set access for the entire component but what I really want is to enable one user group to perform actions on a certain "view", if you will, while another group is denied access to that particular view. I'm guessing it's what's explained here: http://docs.joomla.org/Developing_a_Model-View-Controller_Component/2.5/Adding_ACL#Adding_more_actions.2C_also_at_category_level_and_item_level

The problem I'm having is when I click the Options button and change the access options and save, the selected options aren't saved. I've added the asset functions in my table-class and I've added the asset_id column in my table.

http://i50.tinypic.com/ofsjtt.png

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong? Is it even possible to separate permissions like this?

Answer (score 0):

The viewing access level is called "ViewLevels" http://docs.joomla.org/Access_Control_List/2.5/Tutorial#ACL_View_Access_Levels_Examples.

If you want people to perform certain actions on certain items, then you need to create an other set of permissions for these items different than the component acl.

For example you have a shop component, you have ACL for the component but you can have ACL for the product categories only.